# update state delay in checkbox, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I have to objects `sizes` and `newProduct` , I need to set the available sizes using a checkboxes, it works fine but :

When I check two boxes, the state updates only in the first box , then when pushing the `sizes` object to the `newProduct` object , the state on the `newProduct` did not update until I check the third box (update only the value of the first box)

**Here is my code** :

```
function Products(){

    const [sizes, setSizes] = useState({
        s: false, m: false, l: false, xl: false, xxl: false, xxxl: false
    })
    const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
        productType : "", name : "", price : "", photo : "", sizes : sizes
    })

    const manageSizes = (e) => {
        
        const { name, checked} = e.target
        
        setSizes({...sizes, [name] : checked}) // late (1)
        
        setNewProduct({...newProduct, sizes : sizes}) // late (2)
        
    }
    return (
          {Object.keys(sizes).map((item, index) => (
                <label key={index} htmlFor={item}>{item}
                        <input 
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={sizes[item]}
                        name={item} 
                        onChange={manageSizes}
                        />
                </label>        
          ))}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the new object in setting new product.

```
const manageSizes = (e) => {
    
    const { name, checked} = e.target
   
    setSizes({...sizes, [name] : checked})
    
    setNewProduct({...newProduct, sizes : {...sizes, [name] : checked}}) // <--- new object.
    
}
```

or set it as new variable

```
const manageSizes = (e) => {
    
    const { name, checked} = e.target
    const newSizes = {...sizes, [name]: checked }
   
    setSizes(newSizes) 
    setNewProduct({...newProduct, sizes : newSizes }) // <--- new object.
    
}
```

Comment: yes this works without any errors or warnings thank you .

Answer (score 2):

As `setSizes` is the asynchronous function, you can't get the updated value of `sizes` immediately after setSizes.

You should get it in the `useEffect` with adding a `sizes` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNewProduct({...newProduct, sizes: sizes})
}, [ sizes ])
```

Comment: but how can i implement the `useEffect` hook inside the `manageSize` function ?

Comment: don't implement useEffect inside manageSize function, just define it inside Products() {...}

Comment: it works but there is a warning :  `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'newProduct'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setNewProduct(n => ...)' if you only need 'newProduct' in the 'setNewProduct' call`

Comment: or try with this `setNewProduct(prevProduct => {...prevProduct, sizes: sizes})`

Comment: solution of @semeon works without any warnings , thank you so much for helping